# access to nanosecond in struct inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, inode

In linux kernel v4.19.3

In my module, I need to get the inode last modification time in nanosecondes and not in seconds, but it always returns 0.

struct timespec64   i_mtime;

for example in this code :

```
pr_info("nsec = %ld - sec = %lld\n",inode->i_mtime.tv_nsec,inode->i_mtime.tv_sec);
```

this code returns :

```
nsec = 0 - sec = 1593096577
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, of course, may depend on a specific file system that your inode is located on. Also, there's that unlikely chance that the time was exactly a round number of seconds.

However, the most likely reason for the behaviour you're observing is that in some Linux file systems the nanosecond part of each time-related `timespec` structure in the `inode` structure is set to zero when the inode is created. So, for instance, if you are getting zero nanoseconds in the last-modified time stamp, it likely means that the file has not been modified since its creation.

This is a minimal kernel module that prints the modification time of a predefined file. It compiles and works on Ubuntu with kernel `4.15.0-101-generic`. The module is intentionally not loaded into the kernel and exits after printing out the timestamp values.

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/namei.h>

#define S_NAME  "test.txt"

static int __init s_init(void)
{
        int ret;
        struct path path;

        ret = kern_path(S_NAME, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path);

        if (ret) {
                pr_info("File not found '%s'\n", S_NAME);
        } else {
                pr_info("nsec = %ld - sec = %ld\n",
                        path.dentry->d_inode->i_mtime.tv_nsec,
                        path.dentry->d_inode->i_mtime.tv_sec);
        }

        return -1;
}

module_init(s_init);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Actually, I use a shell script in order to create hundreds of file in one shot, and this happend in the same second... OK, I will try to modify it to see of the nanosecond change. thank you !

Comment: I tried to modify a file, and the nanoseconds stayed at 0.... any idea ?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if I could reproduce your situation. How do you create these files, exactly? What method do you use? What file system these files are created on?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I use the "touch" bash command, by hand, or via a for loop in a shell script. I tried to nano a file in order to change the modification date... same result. Unfortunately, I cannot share with you the VFS YET, I'm not allowed :(

Comment: I don't understand why you can't share the type of your FS. Is that a custom FS type? I've got curious and I have written a minimal kernel module that prints the modification time of a predefined file. The FS is ext4. A file created with any usual editor or from the command prompt (like with `touch` or with `>`) has nanoseconds set no non-zero value on this FS. A file restored from a tar archive has the nanosecond part of modification time as zero. When I add something to the file (modify it) the nanosecond part becomes a non-zero value. All of that is succesfuly shown in the module output.

Comment: I have added the code to the kernel module above. I am thinking that your FS is custom-developed, and so your issue is in the implementation of your custom FS and not in the Linux kernel per se or your understanding of the code that prints out the timestamp values.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem :

This custom FS I'm using, has the s_time_gran of the struct SB (superblock) set at 10⁹, which is a worse granularity available (one second).

I changed it to 1, and I got the nanoseconds.